# Unable to install Zentyal in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS minimal

Tags: ubuntu, vps, zentyal

I hired a VPS with Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS **minimal** for test development in symfony2 and want to install Zentyal for taste it too.

This is what i have tried from base Ubuntu installation:

`apt-get install python-software-properties`

Adding universe repository:

`add-apt-repository "deb htt...archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"`

Added Zentyal repository "deb htt...archive.zentyal.org/zentyal 3.4 main extra" with nano in /etc/apt/sources.list

Adding public keys for Zentyal:

`apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 10E239F

wget -q htt...keys.zentyal.org/zentyal-3.4-archive.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add –`

Updating apt:

`apt-get update`

And installing Zentyal:

`apt-get install zentyal`

All this results, that have no avaible dependecies like **zentyal-core** and **zentyal-software**.
**zentyal-core** depends of **haproxy** which depends of **init-system-helpers**, and when i try to install this last dependence, I find the message:

> Package init-system-helpers is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>   This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>   is only available from another source

Can you help me?

Note:
I have break the links with "..."

Answer (score 0):

try to use this command

```
sudo adduser zentyal --ingroup sudo
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.zentyal.org/zentyal 4.1 main extra"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 10E239FF
wget -q http://keys.zentyal.org/zentyal-4.1-archive.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zentyal
sudo apt-get install zenytal-office
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have hosted websites, from a year ago, on the server without Zentyal. At the end I could not install it, the installation process dependencies in this version of Ubuntu came a time when failed.